# Unable to run SCDF task on Kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, task, spring-cloud-dataflow

I'm unable to run simple task on Kubernetes.

> SCDF version: 1.6.1.RELEASE
>
> Kubernetes version: 1.11.2

```
dataflow:>app register --type task --name timestamp --uri docker:springcloudtask/timestamp-task:1.3.1.RELEASE
Successfully registered application 'task:timestamp'

dataflow:>task create task1 --definition "timestamp"
Created new task 'task1'

dataflow:>task launch --name task1
Command failed org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.rest.client.DataFlowClientException: Failed to resolve application resource: Docker Resource [docker:springcloudtask/timestamp-task:1.3.1.RELEASE]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was already addressed via [spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-kubernetes#328](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-kubernetes/issues/328).

A workaround was included until the release goes out.